# Repeated SUM(field) query optimization

Tags: mysql, optimization, query-optimization

For some summary calculations (to be inserted in a summary table later on) I have a query with some basic maths using repeatdly the same `SUM(field)` ingredients.

Notice that in the following sample piece of code `SUM(price1)` is done 3 times and `SUM(price2)` twice.

```
SELECT customer_id, 
       SUM(price1) AS p1,  
       SUM(price2) AS p2, 
       100*(SUM(price1)-SUM(price2))/SUM(price1) AS discount
FROM myTable
WHERE /* some conditions */
GROUP BY customer_id
```

At first sight this looks pretty inefficient to me.

- Should this be optimized? Or MySQL is doing it internally?
- How can this be rewritten for better performance?

Comment: If you aren't working with huge amounts of data, honestly isn't really any need to optimize it.  The SQL/Data cache is likely saving the sum's anyways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer:  Don't worry.

Long answer:  The cost of computing any function (aggregate or otherwise) is minor compared to the cost of fetching the rows.  Don't fret about the repetition of the function, and don't bother to look for optimizations.